# Excel file (.xlsx) to PDF Conversion using microsoft graph api is ignoring page setup instructions

Tags: excel, pdf, microsoft-graph-api

I already have excel file in .xlsx format.I am trying to convert to pdf using microsoft graph api (by uploading the file to one drive and then downloading it as pdf). I am using the following API call

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/[item-id]/content?format=pdf

I see that the pdf conversion process in above API doesn't consider all the page setup parameters that are set in the underlying .xlsx file. More specifically, I see that converted pdf is always rendered in landscape mode and seems to be ignoring fit to width/height/page settings. If I open the same excel file locally using Excel and save the document as pdf, it renders the document correctly by interpreting all the page setup parameters properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how I can get pdf conversion API to render pdf as per orientation(portrait/landscape) and page width/height settings on the .xlsx file

I have tried multiple smaller files with different page setup parameters but pdf conversion (using rest api) always returns the document in landscape mode and seems to be ignoring fit to page/width/height settings

Comment: Hi, I'm currently facing a similar issue, have you find any answer or workaround ?